# Restrict access to confidential files on server

Tags: php, directory, confidentiality

There might be a pretty straight forward solutions that i'm not seeing and I would really appreciate some help:

- I have an admin online website for my client
- He wishes to make some confidential files available on the admin files (a button to download them)

I'm using PHP for the admin website- the users have to log in to access those pages, any way i can keep those files confidential on the server and have them accessible by a link? Can i make a private directory and make a general php page with password to access them?

Not sure how to go here, thanks a lot!